# Unable to use windowsazure.mobileservices in my mono for android app

Tags: android, windows, azure, mono

I am trying to get Windows Azure Mobile Services up and running but can not for the life of me find the DLL anywhere on my PC. I installed the SDK already.

I thought I read somewhere that this DLL is only available for use in Windows 8 development environments. Is this true? I am running Windows 7. If so is there another way around accessing my database in the cloud?

Comment: I am following https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net
but am still having issues. Trying to install packages via NuGet gives me the following error: 
Could not install package 'System.Spatial 5.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the version of the DLL that Xamarin ported from the original code.  Download it from their component store: http://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-mobile-services/

Answer (score 0):

well that depend on the way you start developing your application.  if you developed the script on Windows Azure Mobile Cloud Service and then download the project from the portal, I am sure you wont face any problems of the above.